# nullreferenceexception was unhandled - c#

Tags: c#

I have downloaded this [PictureBox ImageArray](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21143/PictureBox-Array-in-Visual-Studio-NET)
then I've added a button which will add all it's image to sql server 2005

this is the code:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[] imgArray2;
string c_string = "server=.\\sqlexpress;database=Blue;trusted_connection=true";


for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFiles; i++)
{
    imgArray2[i].Image = Image.FromFile(imgName[i]);
    string name = imgName[i].Substring(imgName[i].LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1, imgName[i].Length - imgName[i].LastIndexOf(@"\") - 1);
    MemoryStream mstr = new MemoryStream();
    imgArray2[i].Image.Save(mstr, imgArray2[i].Image.RawFormat);
    byte[] arrImage = mstr.GetBuffer();
    string cmd = "insert into Images (ImagePart" + i + "Name, ImagePart" + i + ") values (@PName, @Pic)";

    SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(c_string);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmd, c);
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40)).Value = name;
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Pic", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = arrImage;

    try
    {
        c.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        c.Close();
    }

}
```

I've added an `imgArray2[]` so the image from `imgArray[]` won't changes and even though I'm using `imgArray[]` it still throwing the Null error.

The error info highlights the `imgArray2[i].Image = Image.FromFile(imgName[i]);`
it shows nullreferenceexception was unhandled - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: This kind of problem can be solved by using the debugger to track down where the null reference occurred.  Please don't make others debug your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `imgArray` value and it's contents are never initialized.  It needs to be an array capable of holding at least `NumFiles` items and each item needs to be initialized.

```
imgArray2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[NumFiles];
for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFiles; i++)
  imgArray2[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
```

Comment: that and this `imgArray2[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();` after that will do the work

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox[] imgArray2` array before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a brief look and it looks like your `imgArray2` is never instantiated... you just declared a variable and tried to access it